# How can we display a CSS class on the clientside in our React application?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want user to see what styling I have used so how can I send the css class where I have written my styling in react. The JS file and css file are different. In the css file the styling's are wriiten.

```
.SideBar{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: silver;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Now I want this class to appear on my user interface. So what should I write in JS.
import classes from './Project.module.css';

These properties are working fine on the JSX element but I want the user to see these properties. So how can I write in JSX so that user see these properties.

Expected Output :-
On UI

```
.SideBar{
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: silver;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

So what should I do

Comment: Please show us your code to create a reproduceable example

Comment: Maybe this is something for you: https://codepen.io/HerrSerker/pen/875f84b236460677eb5d4e29b3dd54df?editors=0011

Answer (score 1):

You can write the style inside style tag in the component, and then show the user the style tag itself.

Here is how you can write the style tag inside the render function: https://medium.learnreact.com/the-style-tag-and-react-24d6dd3ca974

And look here for showing the style tag itself: https://css-tricks.com/show-and-edit-style-element/.

For example:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Show me your style!</h1>
      
      <style dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: `
      body style { 
        display: block; 
      }
      h1 { 
        color: blue;
       }
    `}} />
    </div>
  );
  }
}
```

Yes, this is ugly, but can work for you.

Good luck!

Comment: Hey, Thank you for helping out. But is there any way possible that I write my stylings in the class in the css file and than I display that in my JS file

Comment: @meetmehta look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55205774/how-to-import-a-css-file-in-a-react-component-as-raw-text/55205882 Other option is to generate the code elsewhere and inject inside the html & the css. but those solutions are even more uglier.

Comment: @meetmehta if you found a better solution- please post it as an answer, if not- please accept the one that helped you. and, upvote will be appreciated. thanks

Comment: As my reputation is less than 15 I cannot upvote any answer. I found the solution thanks to y'all .

Answer (score 0):

in react, if you want to add CSS you have to use **className** in your javascript file.

Example :

**CSS file:**

```
.menu {
background-color: coral;
}
```

**JS File:**

First Import your CSS file in the js file

```
render() {
  return <span className="menu">Menu</span>
}
```

Like this, you can use css in your js file

Comment: Thanks for helping out. But this is not y question. I want the css properties to be displayed as it is on the web.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```js
console.clear();
{


  function getStyle(className) {
    "use strict";
    className = className.replace('.', '\.');
    var styles = Array.from(document.styleSheets).reduce((carry, sheet) => {
      var rules;
      try { // CORS
        rules = sheet.rules || sheet.cssRules;
      } catch (e) {
        return carry;
      }
      if (!rules) { return carry }
      
      rules = Array.from(rules).reduce((carry, rule) => {
      
        if (rule.selectorText && rule.selectorText.match(className)) {
          carry.push(rule.cssText || rule.style.cssText);
        }
        return carry;
      }, []);
      if (rules.length) {
        carry.push(rules)
      }
      return carry;
    }, [])
    return styles[0];
  }

  function getElementsWithClasses() {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[class]'));
  }

  function over(el) {
    var display = document.getElementById('display-fsadhkfjdfkds');
    if (!display) {
      display = document.createElement('div')
      display.setAttribute('id', 'display-fsadhkfjdfkds');
      document.body.append(display);
    }
    display.innerHTML = "";
    var html = Array.from(el.classList).reduce((carry, cl) => {carry += getStyle(`.${cl}`); return carry}, "");
    display.innerHTML = html;
  }
  function out(el) {
    var display = document.getElementById('display-fsadhkfjdfkds');
      if (display) {
        display.remove()
      }
  }
                                     
  var elems = getElementsWithClasses()
  
  
  window.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    if(e.target.classList.length) {
      over(e.target)
    }
  })
  document.addEventListener('mouseout', e => {
    if(e.target.classList.length) {
      out(e.target)
    }
  })
}
```

```css
.abra, .ca {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.abra {
  color: pink;
}
.dabra {
  color: blue;
}
.not-used {
  padding: 200px;
}
.date {
  padding: 20px;  
}

[class]:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 1px #800000;
}

#display-fsadhkfjdfkds {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  width: calc(25vw - 2 * 5px);
  height: calc(50vh - 2 * 5px);
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: cornsilk;
  border: 1px solid darkgreen;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px;
}

html, body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<code class="abra ca dabra" data-do-it="dont">No code</code>
<div class="extra">
  Extra
</div>
<span>No class</span>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="date"><time class="year" style="color: red">2020</time></td>
    <td>Event 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

#### Old

How about with CSS and `:after` pseudo element which has class' attribute as content?

```css
*[class]:after {
  content: "." attr(class);
  color: gray;
  font-size: .75em;
  vertical-align: super;
}
```

```html
<div class="dig"><span>No</span> <span class="spa">questions</span> <span>asked</span></div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping out. But I do not want to show the class name but I want to show the properties which are inside the class which we have written

Comment: The full style declarations? Why do you want to do something that the browser has built in?

Comment: User does not how to use developer tools . So it's nice if they can see it on their screen only.