# Import a file as a string (or source asset) in Gatsby / React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, module, embed

I want to import .ts, .tsx, .js, and .jsx files into a react component and render them within a PrismJS highlighting block. For example, let's say I have a TypeScript file with functionA in it that I want to highlight in my actual website:

`functionA.ts`:

```js
export function functionA() {
    console.log("I am function A!");
}
```

I want to include this in a different component. The problem is, when I import it, I am obviously importing the webpack module version of it. My weak attempt at trying to get my function render in a react component looks like this:

`MyComponent.tsx`:

```
import * as React from "react"
import { functionA } from "./functionA"

export function MyComponent() {
    return (
        <>
            <h1>Here is your code block:</h1>
            <pre>
                <code>
                    {functionA.toString()}
                </code>
            </pre>
        </>
    )
}
```

and what will actually render on the page where the code block is will look something like this:

```
Here is your code block:

WEBPACK__IMPORT.functionA() {
    console.log("I am function A!")
}
```

I can't exactly remember what the `.toString()` function output looked like, but the point is it is NOT just the contents of the file how it appears in a code edit for example - it has been modulized by WebPack.

So, in a Gatsby project, how can i get these various code snippets to be imported directly as a string, purely as they are written, without WebPack enacting its import stuff on it? Is there a plugin or some way to tell Webpack to use the imported file as its `asset/source` module type? I know for MD or MDX files there is the `gatsby-remark-embed-snippet`, but I am building a component based HTML page and can't use MD or MDX files!

It's very late, and perhaps I just can't see the forest from the trees, I know there must be a way to do this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `require` the file using webpack's `raw-loader`, i.e:

```js
const functionA = require("!!raw-loader!./functionA");
```

This works for `create-react-app`, [as in the solution discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55205774/how-to-import-a-css-file-in-a-react-component-as-raw-text), and this works for Gatsby as well!

After using `require` on such a file, the file contents can be rendered in the component as:

```
<pre>{functionA.default.toString()}</pre>
```

It's then up to you to add syntax highlighting using a tool like prism or similar.

Note this solution will only work as long as Gatsby V3 continues to use WebPack v4, as `raw-loader` is deprecated in WebPack v5 and will be phased out for `asset/source` type modules.

Comment: how would I do this with webpack v5 and asset/source?